# Need help with this integral in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I have trouble showing $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}  \int_0^x \vert h\vert ds  = 0$, where $h \in L^p([0,1],m)$ with m is Lebesgue measure, and $1 < p < \infty$.

In my solution I use space duality, and $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$,and then Hölder's inequality to get

$$\begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{q}}} \int_0^x \mathbb{1}_{ [ 0,1 ] (s)  } |h(s)| dm(s)  & =  \int_0^x \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{q}}} \mathbb{1}_{ [ 0,1 ] }(s)|h(s)| dm(s) \\
            & \leq \Big(  \int_0^x  \Big( \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{q}}} \mathbb{1}_{ [ 0,1 ]  }  (s) \Big)^{q} dm(s) \Big)^{\frac{1}{q}} \Big(  \int_0^x  \vert h(s)\vert^p dm(s)   \Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}$$

I am stuck and can't go any further. Can someone help me understand how to continue? Do I do something wrong, or any hint is really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Using `backtick text` does *not* render code on this website. You should use dollar signs, `$`, to write mathematics

Answer (score 1):

You're basically there, but you've confused yourself by bringing $x^{1/q}$ inside the integral. Use the Holder inequality on $h\in L^p([0,x];m)$: $$0\le\int_0^x|h|\,\mathrm{d}m=\int_0^x\chi_{[0,x]}|h|\,\mathrm{d}m\le\|h|_{[0,x]}\|_p\cdot\|\chi_{[0,x]}\|_q=x^{1/q}\cdot\|h|_{[0,x]}\|_p$$Dividing away by $x^{1/q}$ (and ignoring exponent $1/p$ since it is finite) we want to show: $$\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_0^x|h|^p=0$$

Hint: What do you know about (absolute) continuity?

Does this hold for $p=1$, $1/q:=0$? If $p=\infty$, can the limit ever equal $\infty$?